# How to force an incremental Foundry Transforms job to build non-incrementally without bumping the semantic version?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

How can I force a particular dataset to build non-incrementally without changing the semantic version in the transforms repo?

Details about our specific use case:

We have about 50 datasets defined by a single incremental python via manual registration and a for-loop. The input to this transform can be between 100's and 10000's of small gzip files, so when the larger dataset runs, it ends up partitioning all of these into only a handful of well-sized parquet files, which is perfect for our downstream jobs. However, after this job has been running incrementally for months (with files arriving every hour), there will also be a large number of small parquet files in the output. We'd like to be able to force a snapshot build of this single dataset without having to bump the semantic version of the transform which would trigger snapshot builds for all 50 datasets. Is this possible?

I understand a potential workaround could be defining a "max output files" in the transform itself, reading the current number of files in the existing output, and forcing a snapshot if the current exceeds the maximum. However, since this pipeline is time sensitive (needs to run in under an hour), this would introduce a level of unpredictability to the pipeline since the snapshot build takes much longer. We'd like to be able to set these full snapshot builds to run about once a month on a weekend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commit an empty append transaction on the output dataset.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred approach to do this these days, is to use what I call a "snapshot dataset". This approach allows you to inject a snapshot transaction into your pipeline at any arbitrary point, as well as schedule snapshot builds at regular intervals, which can be very useful for keeping long-lived low-latency pipelines performant.

For this, I use a wrapper when declaring my transforms (java transforms, in my case, but it applies similarly to python) which adds an additional input to my transform.

Let's say you start with a transform that reads datasets `A` and `B` and produces dataset `C`. The wrapper will insert an additional dataset as input called `CSnapshotDataset`, as well as generate a transform that produces this (empty) dataset.

The automatically generated transform that produces `CSnapshotDataset` will always put an empty `SNAPSHOT` transaction into the dataset whenever it is build. When there's a new snapshot transaction coming from `CSnapshotDataset`, your transform will output a snapshot transaction as well.

To then snapshot your pipeline from a given point onwards, for instance from and including dataset `C`, you simply select `C`s snapshot dataset (`CSnapshotDataset` in this case) and build it. The next (scheduled) run of the pipeline will snapshot `C` and everything downstream from it.

To run this on a regular interval, you can then set a schedule to build `CSnapshotDataset`.

I apply this wrapper generously (generally to any transform I write) which gives me the flexibility to snapshot the pipeline from any dataset that might need it.

While it's a little more up-front work to set this up, the major advantages with this are:

- It's a single click to kick off a snapshot and a few clicks to set up a scheduled snapshot, rather than having to do multiple `curl` calls
- It keeps the transaction history of the input and output datasets clean
- It happens entirely in-platform with no need for extracting a token, using a command-line, jenkins or similar

Answer (score 0):

I think you could

for the input:

```
input = input.dataframe('current')
```

for the output:

```
output.set_mode('replace')
```

Comment: Please add more detail about your answer, and add some description about step by step questions

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply decide at run time whether to use `TransformOutput.set_mode()` in your output to `replace` or `modify`.
This way, you could decide based on the sizing of your inputs if you'd like to overwrite or append to the output